# Solve Differential Equation using Bessel's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible to solve,
$$(1-x^2)y''+2(x^2-x-1)y'+(-x^2+2x+7- \frac 1{1-x^2})y=0$$
using Bessel's equation,
$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-p^2)y=0 ?$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this has to do with Bessel's equation.  Actually its solutions are elementary functions, not a Bessel in sight:

$$ y \left( x \right) =a\;\sqrt {{x}^{2}-1}\;x{{\rm e}^{x}}+b\;{\frac {{{\rm e}
^{x}} \left(  \left( {x}^{3}-x \right) \ln  \left( x-1 \right) +
 \left( -{x}^{3}+x \right) \ln  \left( x+1 \right) +2\,{x}^{2}-4/3
 \right) }{\sqrt {{x}^{2}-1}}}
$$